# Unable to update the model layer upon CoreAnimation completion

Tags: ios, ios7, core-animation, swift

I have the following function. It's purpose is to animate ui elements out of the the screen's bounds.

```
func animateElementsOut(elements: AnyObject...) {

    var moveOutAnimation : CAKeyframeAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform");
    moveOutAnimation.delegate = self;

    var key1 : NSValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DIdentity);
    var key2 : NSValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-300, 0, 0));

    var values : NSArray = [key1, key2];

    var delayAmount = 0.0;

    moveOutAnimation.values = values;

    moveOutAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;
    moveOutAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn);
    moveOutAnimation.duration = 0.5;

    moveOutAnimation.additive = true;

    for element : AnyObject in elements {
        delayAmount += 0.1;
        moveOutAnimation.removedOnCompletion = true;
        moveOutAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + delayAmount;
        element.layer?.addAnimation(moveOutAnimation, forKey: "move object along the x axis");

        // HERE LIES THE PROBLEM
        element.layer?.position = CGPointMake(-330.0, 0.0);


    }


}
```

Now here's what xCode is complaining about, when I try to update the property directly on the model layer, so that the elements would not reset to their initial positions.

[image]

It's also giving me these weird recommendations:

[image]

Why can't I set the position of the layer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.layer?.position` is an optional chain and may result in nil. You can't assign anything to nil. First make sure you can get the layer and then set its position.

```
if let layer = element.layer {
   layer.position = CGPointMake(-330.0, 0.0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @connor! I can confirm that this did the job, although now everything disappears before I can see any sort of animation happening. I would certainly give this one more thought. :)